# Get class attribute using closest /prev/ filter

Tags: jquery, closest

How can i get class attribute of `<i>` element  when i click on `<a>` Subcategory elements ?

I have tried :

```
$(el).filter("i").attr("class")
$(el).closest("i").attr("class")
```

```html
<ul class="dropdown">
  <li class="dropdown-submenu">
    <i class="fas fa-tools color-1 text-center mr-1"></i>
    <a href="#!" class="list-group-item">Category A</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
          <li>
            <a href="#!" class="list-group-item">Subcategory1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#!" class="list-group-item">Subcategory2</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#!" class="list-group-item">Subcategory3</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `.closest("i")` doesn't work because the `<i>` element is not an ancestor of the `<a>` element. `$(el).closest(".dropdown-submenu").children("i").attr("class")` would work.

Answer (score 1):

The [`.filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) method limits the current collection per the selector supplied. There are no `i` elements that are siblings of `a` elements.

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

The [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method searches the **ancestors** of the elements per the selector supplied. The only `i` element is not an ancestor of any of the `a` elements. However, you can traverse up to a parent/ancestor of the `i` element and then traverse downwards as suggested by @FelixKling:

```
$('a').on('click', function() {
    console.log( $(this).closest("li[class]").find("i[class]").attr("class") );
});
```

**DEMO**

```js
$('a').on('click', function() {
    //$(this).filter("i").attr("class")
    console.log( $(this).closest("li[class]").find("i[class]").attr("class") );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dropdown">
  <li class="dropdown-submenu">
    <i class="fas fa-tools color-1 text-center mr-1"></i>
    <a href="#!" class="list-group-item">Category A</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
          <li>
            <a href="#!" class="list-group-item">Subcategory1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#!" class="list-group-item">Subcategory2</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#!" class="list-group-item">Subcategory3</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `.filter` has nothing to do with siblings.   It's frequently used for siblings, eg `$("li>a").filter(".active")` but that's coincidence that they're siblings or the selector happened to include only siblings

Comment: You're right @freedomn-m. Thank you for pointing that out.